# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined APIFY API

Tags: apify

I just get started to use the free trial APIFY for Instagram scraper till days ago when this ERROR show up and I don't know why. I'm using web plattaform and API both whit this proxy config (I read that it might be related with):

"useApifyProxy": true

"apifyProxyGroups": []

What this ERROR means?

LOG: https://apifier-circular-logs-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/veQ9xFae8mDBWK4Kq.log.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTQHBVH6QKNNBOIQ&Expires=1593307640&Signature=f97xq9xy0lqZdMqgoe0fLNmwQz0%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22veQ9xFae8mDBWK4Kq.log%22

Answer (score 1):

This error happened due to the changes on Instagram's side and is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Note the message in the log:

> You are using Apify proxy but not residential group! It is very likely it will not work properly. Please contact support@apify.com for access to residential proxy.

Comment: Yes I'm agree with that but at the beginning of trial I was working with same data configuration and I didn't have problem.